# WKT to shapefile using arcpy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, well-known-text

I'm trying to convert WKT from an API to a shapefile via arcpy (there is a requirement to use the ArcGIS GUI) and am unable to get arcpy to create the shapefile.

My code:

```
def create_shapefile(self, input_file, data, template):
    try:
        arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(os.path.dirname(input_file), os.path.basename(input_file), 'POLYLINE', template, has_m='ENABLED', has_z='ENABLED')
        insertCursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(input_file, ['SHAPE@', 'OPNUM'])
        for f in data:
            # Manually overriding the geom for purposes of this example
            # Data is valid, I can access all attributes if I print to the GUI
            f['geom'] = 'LINESTRING ZM(-93.8477 45.5571 3340 0,-93.8413 45.5521 3308 6,-93.8356 45.5477 3287 11,-93.8295 45.5430 3271 16,-93.8234 45.5383 3246 21)'
            insertCursor.insertRow((f['geom'], f['opnum']))

    except Exception, e:
        self._catch_error(sys._getframe().f_code.co_name, e)
```

The error in the ArcGIS script dialog is:

```
Error in function: create_shapefile
cannot alter multipart geometry type
```

[image: ArcGIS screenshot]

Edit: Updated to new error after reply about using SHAPE@ instead of SHAPE@WKT

Comment: Your WKT **is** invalid. It should be `LINESTRING ZM ...` if it contains Z and M values. I would use the geometry constructor and `shape@` in the cursor. Don't forget to apply the correct `SpatialReference`

Comment: Thanks @Vince - I did not know about shape@ vs shape@wkt and can't believe I missed the ZM! I have updated the question with the new error. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to have a complete code sample with proper indentation, and an error message that specifies the line number.

Comment: Data Access cursors take a row, which should be an array.  I believe `Shape@` requires a `Geometry` object, not a string, but I can't find a WKT constructor for Geometry.

Comment: The missing ZM was the root cause. SHAPE@WKT is in the documentation (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/analyze/arcpy-data-access/insertcursor-class.htm) but only works with a valid WKT. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `'SHAPE@WKT'` instead of `'SHAPE@'`. `SHAPE@` requires a geometry object as an input.

```
def create_shapefile(self, input_file, data, template):
    try:
        arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(os.path.dirname(input_file), os.path.basename(input_file), 'POLYLINE', template, has_m='ENABLED', has_z='ENABLED')
        insertCursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(input_file, ['SHAPE@WKT', 'OPNUM'])
        for f in data:
            # Manually overriding the geom for purposes of this example
            # Data is valid, I can access all attributes if I print to the GUI
            f['geom'] = 'LINESTRING ZM(-93.8477 45.5571 3340 0,-93.8413 45.5521 3308 6,-93.8356 45.5477 3287 11,-93.8295 45.5430 3271 16,-93.8234 45.5383 3246 21)'
            insertCursor.insertRow((f['geom'], f['opnum']))

    except Exception, e:
        self._catch_error(sys._getframe().f_code.co_name, e)
```

Comment: Converting back to SHAPE@WKT and fixing the missing ZM did it. Thanks to you and @vince for your help!